# yAxis tickPositioner label on column range chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lunchboxbill/cnGXj/

I am using the column range chart to display a range of dates (in a similar fashion to a type of gantt chart).

I'm using the tickPositioner function to do some calcualtions as the duration of each month in the chart may differ.

The tick positions will now respect months with 28/29/30/31 days in. In an earlier version the tickInterval was hard coded to 31 days.

UNCOMMENT LINE 43

```
//return gridLines;
```

It appears everything is working, except now the label no longer picks up the "Jan 13" style date. It is using the timestamp and then doing some of it's own number formatting on it.

Is there a way to retain the "Jan 13" label style?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `dateTimeLabelFormats`, use `labels.format`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/cnGXj/1/

```
    "yAxis": {
        "labels": {
            format: "{value:%b %y}"
        },
     }
```